# Coordinates Function that updates lists and stores them to be called

Tags: python, python-3.x

The function below stores two arrays 'a' and 'b' to be used in a linear regression graph. The function is called to retrieve the coordinates elsewhere in the program using coords(0, 0) so the lists aren't updated but are just returned. And then coords(x, y) is called when adding coordinates to each list. However when they are added they aren't getting stored as when coords(0, 0) is called to retrieve the updated lists it just returns 'a' and 'b'

x = [4,5] y = [9,10] coords(x, y) should then return ([0,1,2,3,4,5], [5,6,7,8,9,10]). I want these to then be stored so coords(0, 0) doesn't add anything else but still returns ([0,1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]) instead of just 'a' and 'b'. How would I go about doing this?

```
def coords(x, y)
    a = [0,1,2,3]
    b = [5,6,7,8]
    xList = a
    yList = b
    if x == 0:
        return(xList, yList)
    else:
        xList = xList + x
        yList = yList + y
        return(xList, yList)
```

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Can you provide a bit more context for this? Why can't you store the arrays outside the function, or even use a class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coordinates List that stores updated lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921050/coordinates-list-that-stores-updated-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are mutable and you are creating `a` and `b` for every function call. So you need to make them global.
Try this:

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
b = [5,6,7,8]
def coords(x, y):
    if x == 0:
        return(a, b)
    else:
        a.extend(x)
        b.extend(y) # Faster and recommended way of adding elements to a #list.
        return(a, b)
```

Comment: Doesn't `.extend()` return `None`? I'm not sure how @tomparko got this to work...

Comment: Yeah, removing the `global` and `a =`, `b =` fixes it. Did you actually run this?

Comment: thanks @amc i was in a hurry and didn't see that. thanks again.